Detect build errors when launching Delphi compiler (dcc32.exe) from the command line
Our Delphi project can be built directly from the IDE, of course. But launching from the command line allows the process of building multiple projects to be automated. We are using:
ShellExecute(0,
    'open',
    PChar('[PATH-TO-DELPHI]\Bin\DCC32.EXE'),
    PChar('-B [PATH-TO-PROJECT]\MyProject.dpr'),
    PChar('[PATH-TO-PROJECT]'),
    SW_HIDE);

Normally this works great when there are no code or build errors, and ShellExecute returns a value of "42". However, if there are build errors, the return value is still "42".
You could build the project in the IDE to find the error(s). But is it possible to detect compilation errors from the command line, or to check some file or log to see if the build was successful or not?

Here's a procedure that waits for the process to finish and returns the exit code (0 for success, non-zero for failure):
uses
  Winapi.ShellAPI;

function RunAndWait(hWnd: HWND; filename: string; Parameters: string; var ProcExitCode: Cardinal): Boolean;
var
  sei: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@sei, SizeOf(sei));
  sei.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  sei.Wnd := hwnd;
  sei.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS or SEE_MASK_NOASYNC or SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
  sei.lpVerb := PChar('open');
  sei.lpFile := PChar(Filename);
  if parameters <> '' then
    sei.lpParameters := PChar(parameters);
  sei.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

  Result := ShellExecuteEx(@sei);
  try
    WaitForSingleObject(sei.hProcess, INFINITE);

    // If ShellExecuteEx succeeded, then get the exit code of the process we ran
    if Result then
      if not GetExitCodeProcess(sei.hProcess, ProcExitCode) then
        raise Exception.Create('Error ' + IntToStr(GetLastError) + ' during GetExitCodeProcess call');

  finally
    CloseHandle(sei.hProcess);
  end;
end;


Works! sei.nShow := SW_HIDE; is better for automation. And ProcExitCode has a type of Cardinal, with a return of 0 (success) or 1 (errors).

Use CreateProcess() (or ShellExecuteEx()) instead of ShellExecute(). That way, you can get a HANDLE to the process, then use WaitForSingleObject() to wait for the process to end, and finally get its exit code with GetExitCodeProcess().
var
  cmd: string;
  si: TStartupInfo;
  pi: TProcessInformation;
  exitCode: DWORD;

cmd := '"[PATH-TO-DELPHI]\Bin\DCC32.EXE" -B "[PATH-TO-PROJECT]\MyProject.dpr"';
UniqueString(cmd);

si := Default(TStartupInfo);
si.cb := sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

if not CreateProcess(nil, PChar(cmd), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, PChar('[PATH-TO-PROJECT]'), si, pi) then
  RaiseLastOSError;

CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, exitCode);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

// use exit Code as needed...


Nice, also works! I found constructing cmd := Format('%s -B %s', [fullPathToCompiler, fullPathToProject]); to be easier to read.

You should at least put quotes around the paths, eg: Format('"%s" -B "%s"',...)
